# I Can't Find Any Animation Software That Supports Sound

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, software-center, animations

I just need a link to some animation software that supports sound. I've downloaded Pencil, Pencil2D, Synfig, and Tupi, but none of them seem to support sound, or aren't able to play the sound for some reason. It would help me a great deal if there was some other software I haven't tried, or a way to fix the software I already have.

Comment: Have you tried Blender? It's a 3D modelling tool, but I believe it supports sound and animations.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all animation softwares support sound. They actually have sound layer that you can use.

For example Synfig animation software has a layer for that.

have you looked at [Synfig Sound Layer](http://wiki.synfig.org/Sound_Layer)